# WatchKit: Detect if app was launched from glance/complication

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication, apple-watch-glances

Is there a way to detect if an Apple Watch App was launched by the user tapping the apps glance or complication?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to implement the handleUserActivity method in your main InterfaceController.

```
- (void)handleUserActivity:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  //Your code
 }
```

You can find more info in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/handleUserActivity:

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question but thought it's worth answering in case anyone is still interested!

As jmgomez says above, implement the - handleUserActivity: method, but specifically, in that method you can check:

```
if (userInfo[CLKLaunchedTimelineEntryDateKey] != nil)
```

as a complication adds this to userInfo, so if there is a value there, you are launching from your complication.

hope this helps someone.